# Create DXGIFactory

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d11, directx-12, dxgi

Any reason to create IDXGIFactory1 and then query IDXGIFactory5:

```
CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory));
factory->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory5));
```

Instead of just create IDXGIFactory5:

```
CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory5));
```

?

Why might I need two different interface versions (factory1 and factory5) in the same application when factory5 has all methods of factory1 (I think it's not for backward compatibility)?

Same question for `ID3D11Device`, `ID3D11Device5` and `ID3D11DeviceContext`, `ID3D11DeviceContext4`.

Answer (score 0):

[DXGI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi) ships with Windows since Windows Vista. So, with newer versions of Windows came newer versions of DXGI.

You don't see that reflected in the official documentation because Microsoft only mentions the supported versions to date (this is not 100% true everywhere but often we see that).

So since `IDXGIFactory5` [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_5/nn-dxgi1_5-idxgifactory5) displays this:

[image]

It means `IDXGIFactory5` is supported on Windows 10 (which is still supported as of today). If you check `IDXGIFactory6` [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_6/nn-dxgi1_6-idxgifactory6), it says:

[image]

We can't go back in time, but, for example, Windows 7 only supports DXGI up to `IDXGIFactory2`.

You can also check header files (dxgi1_5.g, dxgi1_6.h, etc.) because sometimes the doc is wrong... but... headers can also be modified with newer versions of SDK.

As for using `CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory5));` directly, it should work (and if it does then it's fine) since this is the purpose of accepting an IID-type argument in the first place, but experience shows that sometimes this kind of shortcut is not supported by the underlying implementation for some reason.

Note: you can also use the exact same code on lower version of Windows where you should get an `E_NOTINTERFACE` error, which is expected and normal behavior.

The story is about the same with Direct3D and Direct2D object models (and the whole Windows COM-based API basically).

Comment: So as I understand I need this if I want to support several Windows versions?

For example, I want to support Windows 10 and Windows 7, then I should create IDXGIFactory1 using CreateDXGIFactory1() and then try to Query IDXGIFactory5.

Then for common methods (which are in both IDXGIFactory1 and IDXGIFactory5) I should use IDXGIFactory1 (this guarantees me that they will work on both versions of Windows) and for new methods (Windows 10 only) - IDXGIFactory5?

Comment: Yes you should always use the smallest version number (when possible) to guarantee a maximum compatibility with older versions of Windows. If you do require some higher number version, you can QueryInterface for it and if you get an error ask the user to upgrade Windows for example

Comment: Thank you a lot